# Counter overflow error

Tags: vba, excel

I am counting the amount of times a phrase appears in a column. However when I have a large dataset it seems to produce an overflow error.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Count
Dim count As Integer

Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "Bob")

Count = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2,8)

End Sub
```

Is there any way to get around this error when the count is too big?

Comment: Integer is only 16 bit in VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy solution is to declare **count** variable as follows :

```
Dim count As Long
```